# How to assign IP to physical machines?

Tags: networking, vmware-esxi, ip, dhcp

Excuse my ignorance, I want to know if its possible to setup untangle in ESXI such that it will be able to assign IPs to physical machines outside the ESXI box.

Here is my setup:

1) Management Network -> vswitch0 -> vmnic1

2) UntangleVM(vnet0) -> vswitch1 -> vmnic2

3) UntangleVM(vnet1) -> vswitch2 -> vmnic3 -> physical switch - > physical machines. [This is what I cant get to work]

All the virtual machines connected to vswitch2 get the correct IPs from untangle's DHCP. However, all the physical machines behind vmnic3 get nothing. Everything is set to promiscuous mode.

If possible, how can I get "3)" to work or what do you recommend to achieve something similar to "3)".

Let me know if you need more context.

Thanks for your precious time.

-newbie

Answer (score 1):

Do you have DHCP Relay configured if the switches exist on different subnets?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing innate about the ESXi platform that would prevent the from working. Have you tried running packet captures at various places on the network? I have no experience with Untangle specifically, but I assume they're using the standard linux dhcpd. Are you sure it's listening on the correct interface? If your graph is accurate, it seems like it is, but it's something to check.

I assume there are no ACLs or the like on the "physical switch" you mention, correct?

Try to do a few packet captures, starting with the untangle box itself, to see if it's even receiving the DHCP requests from clients outside of the ESX environment.

Comment: I'll get back to you after I make the captures.